# How to remove current row from table in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in html as follows

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>test content</td>
<td><input type="button" onClick="remove()"></td>
</tr>
....
...

</tbody>
</table>
```

now if the same pattern continues, i want to remove a row if a remove button is clicked on that row. how do i achieve the same with jQuery?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Nicer:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

[More on closest()](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1728-jQuery-s-Closest-Method-Returns-Only-One-Ancestor.htm)

```
<input type="button" onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();">
```

**This has the benefit of working no matter what your HTML looks like in the cell.**

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" onClick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();">
```

Or you can make it more generic like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $(".btn").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
  });
</script>

<tr>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: probably want to use a class instead of an id though.

Comment: if he wants to remove the row, I would include a 'tr' inside your code, in case he ever adds any more elements like a div.  Then your code will break, but @alt's code won't.