# How to remove a row from a table

Tags: php, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have an html table, and on each row, i would like to add a delete button. 
When the user clicks on it, I would like to do two things:

1) remove the row from the table.
2) extract data from the row that was removed - a particular cell, and then make an ajax call using this value to a function that will remove the record from the database.  The function returns a fresh list of items, which i will then use to redisplay the same table.

I found the following post from someone else on stackoverflow: 
[How to remove current row from table in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161991/how-to-remove-current-row-from-table-in-jquery)

So I guess that addresses point number one. But I don't know how to modify the code in the selected answer of the post to allow for grabbing the id value in the row, and then making an ajax call.

```
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"  id="databaserecords">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Voice</th>
              <th>Jumbo</th>
              <th>Mode</th>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

          <?php foreach ($dblist as $record): ?>
              <tr>          
              <td class ='recordId'><?php echo $record['Id'] ?></td>
              <td class ='recordName'><?php echo $record['Name'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record['Status'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record['Voice'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $record['Jumbo'] ?></td>
              <td class='recordmode'><?php echo $record['Mode'] ?></td>
              <td><button id="deleteRecord">Delete Record</button></td>
            </tr>
          <?php endforeach ?>


 <script>

    $('#deleteRecord').live('click', function()  {

                //get a count of all records. only allowed to delete if you have more than one record.
                var recCount = $('#databaserecords tbody tr').length;

                if (recCount > 1)
                {
                    $thevalueIwanttoSave = $(this).closest('recordId').val();
                                alert($thevalueIwanttoSave);
                            }

    });

 </script>
```

Right now, the alert always says that my variable is undefined. 
Can you point me in the right direction?  I do know how to code an ajax call... I think I just need help with grabbing the value from the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selector is not correct.

```
$thevalueIwanttoSave = $(this).parent().siblings('.recordId').text();
```

`closest` selects the closest parent of the element(*recordId* is not parent/grandparent or.. of your button element) and you have also missed a `.` for class selector. `val` is used for getting/setting values of form elements, for td elements you should use `text` or `html` method. Also note that **IDs must be unique**(you can use classes instead) and `live` method is deprecated, you can use `on` method.

```
$('#databaserecords').on('click', '.deleteRecord', function() { 

    var recCount = $('#databaserecords tbody tr').length;

    if (recCount > 1) {
        var text = $(this).parent().siblings('.recordId').text();
        alert(text);
        // $(this).closest('tr').remove()
    }

});​
```

- [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$thevalueIwanttoSave = $(this).parent('tr').find('.recordId').text();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the ID in an attribute on your delete button and you can just get it via jQuery.

in your php loop:

```
<button class="deleteRecord" recordID="<?php echo $record['Id'] ?>">Delete Record</button>
```

in JQuery on

```
$(".deleteRecord").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("recordID");
    ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

it should be `.recordId`, not `recordId`

```
$thevalueIwanttoSave = $(this).closest('.recordId').val();
    alert($thevalueIwanttoSave);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a `.` to select the element with class recordId. Also use text() to get the value:

```
$thevalueIwanttoSave = $(this).siblings('.recordId').text();
alert($thevalueIwanttoSave);
```